# Insert with select posgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to insert new roles into my app, but only for several users. I can get all their ids by select statement.

So the role for all of them is `'COOL_ROLE'`

Table `account_role` with roles looks like

```
+------------+-------+
| account_id | roles |
+------------+-------+
```

And my statement should just insert many ids with the same role
I have tried

```
INSERT INTO accout_role (accout_id, roles)
VALUES((SELECT..),'COOL_ROLE')
```

but I get error **org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL Error [21000]: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression**

When I remove () in expression

```
INSERT INTO accout_role (accout_id, roles)
VALUES(SELECT..,'COOL_ROLE')
```

I get **org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"**

How can I insert several ids with the same role?

Comment: Simply don't use `VALUES`. You can use the output of a `SELECT` directly as the source of an `INSERT`, adding new columns as required.

Comment: Use `SELECT` directly. `VALUES` is only used to specify values explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `insert into ... select`:

```
insert into account_role (accout_id, roles)
select id, 'COOL_ROLE'
from account
where ...
```

Comment: the select statement is so complicated! I have left join it it and many where

Comment: @СеменНемытов it doesn't matter, this will still work

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `values`:

```
INSERT INTO account_role (account_id, roles)
    SELECT account_id, 'COOL_ROLE'
    FROM . . . ;
```

Comment: the select statement is so complicated! I have left join it it and many where

Comment: @СеменНемытов . . . It is the same question but simpler because you don't have `values`.